# How to disallow this snake movement exploit? - pygame

Tags: python

Here is the logic for my snake movement:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("UP") and playerMovementY != 1:
  playerMovementX = 0
  playerMovementY = -1
elif keyboard.is_pressed("DOWN") and playerMovementY != -1:
  playerMovementX = 0
  playerMovementY = 1
elif keyboard.is_pressed("LEFT") and playerMovementX != 1:
  playerMovementY = 0
  playerMovementX = -1
elif keyboard.is_pressed("RIGHT") and playerMovementX != -1:
  playerMovementY = 0
  playerMovementX = 1
```

The problem is that though this works pretty well, there's a **slight exploit** that you can do where **if you push left to go left, and then push up and right at just the right moment, you are able to turn around**, and obviously you shouldn't be able to do that in snake.

Is there a way I can rewrite this to make that exploit not possible?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You need to wait until the snake has moved one square until it's allowed to turn again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com . The question is fundamentally about how to design the game logic, not about how to write the code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to mkrieger for the answer

Though they did not provide code, I was able to implement exactly what they said, **here's what I did**

```
if just_turned == 0:
  if keyboard.is_pressed("UP") and playerMovementY != 1:
    playerMovementX = 0
    playerMovementY = -1
    just_turned = 1
  elif keyboard.is_pressed("DOWN") and playerMovementY != -1:
    playerMovementX = 0
    playerMovementY = 1
    just_turned = 1
  elif keyboard.is_pressed("LEFT") and playerMovementX != 1:
    playerMovementY = 0
    playerMovementX = -1
    just_turned = 1
  elif keyboard.is_pressed("RIGHT") and playerMovementX != -1:
    playerMovementY = 0
    playerMovementX = 1
    just_turned = 1
```

As you can see, I added a just_turned variable that is set to 0 initially and is set to 1 when you turn

```
while running:
  global just_turned
  playerPos[0] += playerMovementX
  playerPos[1] += playerMovementY
  just_turned = 0
  time.sleep(0.15)
```

Then I set it to 0 at the end of the code to move the snake (I will fix this movement for the different segments when I implement the apple).